# Continuous deployment with Microsoft Azure

Tags: windows, azure, continuous-integration, release-management, continuous-deployment

If a worker role or for that matter web roles are continuously serving both long/short running requests. How does continuous delivery work in this case? Obviously pushing a new release in the cloud will abort current active sessions on the servers. What should be the strategy to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Services have production and staging slots, so you can change it whenever you want. Continuous D or I can be implemented by using Visual Studio Team Services, and i would recommend it - we use that. As you say, it demands to decide when you should switch production and staging slots (for example, we did that when the user load was very low, in our case it was a night, but it can be different in your case). Slots swapping is very fast process and it is (as far as i know) the process of changing settings behind load balancers not physical deployment.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/#step6

UPD - i remember testing that, and my experience was that incoming connections were stable (for example, RDP) and outgoing are not. So, i can not guarantee that existing connections will be ended gracefully, but from my experience there were no issues.

Comment: For busy services like youtube where users are watching and uploading content all the time, i wonder how google handles this situation. Is there a way to preserve users sessions and making transition to a new build without terminating any user session?

Comment: This is not as complicated as you would think. Youtube, netflix, hbo, hulu, they all send you small chunks of video, typically 2-4 seconds in length in sequence, so that they can adjust the quality of video in response to your bandwidth changing. Even if you're watching a 2 hour movie, you're really just looking at a series of very short videos that a load balancer easilly can swap out of.

Comment: Thanks Pedro! That is the very good note. I would add that your project should not be consisted from one instance that is "down" when updated. Typically, you have multiple instances serving requests and you update it once by one - that is how updates are working in Azure when you have a few instances.